# itextpdf 7.2.4 read pdf ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: itext, itext7

I have been using itext lib to merge PDF files with success.

But recently the user had reported an error when converting 2 of the PDF files. I have manage the get the files and by reading with the following code it throws the same exception single every time.

```
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(new File("C:\myfile\file1.pdf"));
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(fis);
PdfDocument input = new PdfDocument(reader);
```

Stack trace below

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 75
at com.itextpdf.io.source.PdfTokenizer.decodeStringContent(PdfTokenizer.java:600)
at com.itextpdf.io.source.PdfTokenizer.decodeStringContent(PdfTokenizer.java:645)
at com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfString.decodeContent(PdfString.java:286)
at com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfString.generateValue(PdfString.java:250)
at com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfString.getValue(PdfString.java:141)
at com.itextpdf.kernel.crypto.securityhandler.StandardSecurityHandler.getIsoBytes(StandardSecurityHandler.java:93)
at com.itextpdf.kernel.crypto.securityhandler.StandardHandlerUsingStandard40.initKeyAndReadDictionary(StandardHandlerUsingStandard40.java:189)
at com.itextpdf.kernel.crypto.securityhandler.StandardHandlerUsingStandard40.<init>(StandardHandlerUsingStandard40.java:81)
at com.itextpdf.kernel.crypto.securityhandler.StandardHandlerUsingStandard128.<init>(StandardHandlerUsingStandard128.java:60)
at com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfEncryption.<init>(PdfEncryption.java:235)
at com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfReader.readDecryptObj(PdfReader.java:1406)
at com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfReader.readPdf(PdfReader.java:765)
at com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfDocument.open(PdfDocument.java:2008)
at com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfDocument.<init>(PdfDocument.java:220)
at com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfDocument.<init>(PdfDocument.java:202)
at itext.Test.main(Test.java:20)
```

Please help.

Comment: Apparently the user provides pdfs that are broken. It looks like an error in the encryption information.

Comment: @mkl I am able to view the pdf file in all pdf reader program w/o err, and this is the second time the user hitting this error with a different PDF than the 1st time

Comment: *"I am able to view the pdf file in all pdf reader program w/o err"* - that hardly means anything. Pdf viewers generally are very lax and repair (by guesswork) many errors. So your observation merely means that the file is not too broken for repair. While that suffices for a pdf viewer (where the human in front of the screen can determine that a repair attempt failed because they only see gibberish), an automatic pdf processor should not be so lenient because in general there is no such human testing the pdf before it is distributed/archived/...